# Eliminar posiciones en array en php

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy haciendo un carrito con `PHP`, mi problema es que solo me esta eliminando la posición 0 del array. 
Acá dejo el código, espero me puedan dar una luz con esto, de antemano gracias.

Esta es la función en `PHP` de eliminar:

```
// funciones carrito
if(isset($_POST['btnCar'])){

    session_start();

    switch($_POST['btnCar']){

    // Borrar de carrito
        case 'del':

        $idEliminado = $_POST['id'];

        foreach($_SESSION['carrito'] as $item => $producto){
            if($producto['id'] == $idEliminado){
                unset($_SESSION['carrito'][$item]);
                $respuesta = array(                
                'respuesta' => 'exito',
                'idEliminado' => $idEliminado,
                'cuenta' => count($_SESSION['carrito'])
                );
            }                
            die(json_encode($respuesta));
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, puedes poner el código de la clase formCar.

Comment: lo asignas a la posicion 0 debes hacer `foreach($_SESSION['carrito'][0] as $item => $producto){` y  `unset($_SESSION['carrito'][0][$item]);`

Comment: Ya he agregado la tabla donde esta la clase q uso en ajax.

Comment: El problema esta en el die tal vez; el hecho de que siempre se llame no importa si se cumple o no la condición eso lo que hace es que en la primera iteración siempre se salga del ciclo por consiguiente no sigue buscando y no elimina otro que este en una posición mayor al primer indice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
// funciones carrito
if(isset($_POST['btnCar'])){

    session_start();

    switch($_POST['btnCar']){

    // Borrar de carrito
        case 'del':

        $idEliminado = $_POST['id'];
        //Creas una respuesta para el caso en el que no se encuentre el id que se pasa
        $respuesta = array('respuesta' => 'error', 'idEliminado' => 0, 'cuenta' => count())

        foreach($_SESSION['carrito'] as $item => $producto){
            if($producto['id'] == $idEliminado){
                unset($_SESSION['carrito'][$item]);
                //Recreas la respuesta satisfactoria
                $respuesta = array(                
                'respuesta' => 'exito',
                'idEliminado' => $idEliminado,
                'cuenta' => count($_SESSION['carrito'])
                );
            }    
        }
        //Devuelves el resultado de la operación siempre
        die(json_encode($respuesta));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo ese era el error.

Comment: No hay de que para eso estamos ;P